# Why validation triggers error in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Faced the problem while using Laravel 4 validation. Here's the code:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
              array(
                  'surname' => ['Laravel'],
              ),
              array(
                  'surname' => 'integer|alpha_dash'
              )
        );
        $validator->passes();        
        var_dump($validator->failed());
```

It causes error: **Error: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

Lets suppose surname comes from user and it can be array or string.

I have two questions:

1. Why alpha_dash causes error instead of normal validation error?
2. Why validation continues to 'alpha_dash' rule after we got FALSE on 'integer' rule? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I just did to test arrays:

Created some fields the way you are doing:

```
<input type="text" name="user[surname][0]">
<input type="text" name="user[surname][1]">
```

And validated one of them:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    array('user.surname.0' => 'required|min:5')
);

var_dump($validator->passes());
```

Then I just did it manually:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(
    array(
        'user' => ['surname' => [ 0 => 'Laravel'] ],
    ),
    array('user.surname.0' => 'required|min:5')
);
```

And it worked on both for me.

If you need to analyse something Laravel doesn't provide, you can extend the Validator by doing:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value == 'foo';
});
```

**EDIT**

But, yeah, there is a bug on it, if you do:

```
$validator = \Validator::make(
    array(
        'user' => ['surname' => [ 0 => 'Laravel'] ],
    ),
    array('user.surname.0' => 'integer|alpha_dash')
);
```

It will give you a

```
"Error: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given".
```

Here's the Laravel issue posted by the OP: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2457.

Comment: I know that's an array. I'm asking why i have error instead of standart validation message? What if user posts an array?

Comment: Because you are supposed to send the correct data to be processed by the validator, validator is expecting a string there, not an array.

Comment: print_r(\Input::all());
   Array ( [surname] => Array ( [0] => Laravel ) )

Comment: That's odd. Could you share your view?

Comment: Here's an example of get query: ?user[surname][0]=Laravel

Comment: Yeah, I was imagining something like this. Fill a bug on github. Laravel will have to handle arrays in validation values.

Comment: You're wrong. You dont know what user attemps to pass to your script. Your validation will crash if i want to compromise app and pass to you more complex array

Comment: I might be, but can you provide some data that would break that so I can test it here? I just tested using `array('user' => ['surname' => [ 0 => ['Laravel' => ['Framework' => ['4' => ['1' => '0']]]]]]),` and it didn't broke.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42206/discussion-between-trerums-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro)